# Spacing of the x-axis in a marginal effects plot using R & ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, marginal-effects

After fitting a regression model, I plotted marginal effects using *ggpredict()* and *plot_model()*. The resulting plot is great, just the spacing of the x-axis is too wide.

[image: Marginal effect plot]

There are only two levels (X.0 and X.1) in the X variable used for grouping. How can I reduce the space between both plot elements?